# Trouble in getting _bss_start through in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I wanted to print the address of bss start using CONSTANT __bss_start . I made a simple programe which wil print the addres of bss section.Below is the code

```
 section .bss
 section .data
 x db "value is =%ld"
 section .text
;extern alt_u32* __bss_start;

global main
extern  __bss_start;
extern printf
main:
mov bx,__bss_start
push bx
push x
call printf
add esp,8
ret
```

When I run gcc -m32 -o bss_start.o to get final executable,getting below error

```
    bss_start.asm:(.text+0x2): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_16 against symbol `__bss_start' defined in *ABS* section in bss
```

What could be problem here??

Comment: Use a 32-bit register (e.g. `ebx`).

Comment: Thanks @Michael , I don't know why did I use bx register here,In my earlier programes  I am only using ebx more ofen or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `__bss_start` will be a 32-bit address in the process address space, and you're trying to fit it into a 16-bit register. You're almost there (in fact, your stack cleanup `add esp,8` is precisely right!), but you need three modifications:

1. `mov bx, __bss_start` needs to be `mov ebx, __bss_start` (32-bit wide).
2. `push bx` needs to be `push ebx`, again to be 32-bit wide.
3. I modified `x db value is =%ld` to `x db value is=%x` so that I could check the output against `objdump -t`.

This gives me a matching value to objdump.

Also, just for extra juice, I got the C runtime library to clean itself up afterwards by adding:

```
xor eax, eax
push eax
call exit
```

with an `extern exit`. But you don't need this, however, I would `xor eax,eax` to set the return code.

Comment: Thanks @Antony for your answer,One more thing Would like do we have symbol like __bss_end which points to bss section's end,Because When  I use __bss_end ,getting error like  undefined reference to `__bss_end

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar There isn't an explicit end for the bss section, but, in the binary I compiled, `_end` points to the end of the executable and the `.bss` section. You could control this yourself with linker scripts and actually define your own `__bss_end` this way, too.

Comment: Fine Antony ,Got the point. For me also its _end symbol which gives me _bss_end

Comment: @Amit Good good :) The documents to linker scripts are available here: http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.22/ld/Scripts.html but do be careful what you do (i.e. don't try to hard code paddrs with the `AT` macro - let ld-linux handle all that).